# how to run word count program in hadoop 2.6.0 installed on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: hadoop

```
sudo javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar WordCount.java
```

I do not understand the command that I need to write in place of `javac -classpath`.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Answer (score 2):

You should also add output destination folder path for class files in your command.

Follow these steps.

- Create the destination directory for the class files. For Example, it is called *intersect_classes*.

  ```
  mkdir intersect_classes
  ```
- Compile the program.

  ```
  sudo javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar -d intersect_classes WordCount.java
  ```
- Create the jar "intersect.jar"

  ```
  jar -cvf intersect.jar -C intersect_classes/ .
  ```
- Copy the input file from the local source to the hadoop file system

  ```
  bin/hadoop dfs -put <path of input in localFileSystem>/inputfile <path of input in HDFS FileSystem>/inputfile
  ```
- Run the application :

  ```
  bin/hadoop jar intersect.jar Intersect <path of input in HDFS FileSystem>/inputFile <paht of output in HDFS FileSystem>/output
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  bin/hadoop dfs -cat <path of output in HDFS FileSystem>/output/*
  ```

The output folder may contain more than one output files depending on the number of reducers. The contents of the exact file can be viewed by replacing '*' with the filename present inside the output folder.

- Retrieve the output file from the hadoop file system to the local destination:

  ```
  bin/hadoop dfs -get <path of output in HDFS FileSystem>/output <path of output in HDFS FileSystem>/output
  ```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Tim , question content is poorly written that's why i prefer to answer a question by just recommending a reference.

Comment: A poor question doesn't mean you can't give a good answer.

Comment: @Tim and Pilot6 , i edited my answer and added relevant steps to be follow , which might solve this problem.

Comment: How do we find the path of input in the HDFS FileSystem?

Comment: @VineetKaushik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437550/what-is-the-hdfs-location-on-hadoop